# Paging in cassandra through hector API for user defined queries

Tags: java, cassandra

Is it possible to achieve paging in cassandra through hector API for user defined queries.

If yes, how?

Comment: What you are asking seems very much possible maybe some example of user defined queries would help us in providing a solution

Comment: @abhijit select * from <column family> <paging logic>

Answer (score 0):

I have added a basic method, rest of things you have to handle. Here, as you can see we have defined page size as 100 rows, each having 10 columns. Now after the first iteration you have to some how store the last key value, which will the starting point for the iteration.

```
    int row_count = 100;

    RangeSlicesQuery<UUID, String, Long> rangeSlicesQuery = HFactory
        .createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, UUIDSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), LongSerializer.get())
        .setColumnFamily("Column Family")
        .setRange(null, null, false, 10)
        .setRowCount(row_count);

    UUID last_key = null;

    while (true) {
        rangeSlicesQuery.setKeys(last_key, null);
        System.out.println(" > " + last_key);

        QueryResult<OrderedRows<UUID, String, Long>> result = rangeSlicesQuery.execute();
        OrderedRows<UUID, String, Long> rows = result.get();
        Iterator<Row<UUID, String, Long>> rowsIterator = rows.iterator();

        if (last_key != null && rowsIterator != null) rowsIterator.next();   

        while (rowsIterator.hasNext()) {
          Row<UUID, String, Long> row = rowsIterator.next();
          last_key = row.getKey();

          if (row.getColumnSlice().getColumns().isEmpty()) {
            continue;
          }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't take in consideration that I have to fire my own query like select * from <column family> <paging logic> which I am not able to see in your example

Comment: i haven't mention those thing in the example, as those things depends on your where clause, whether <paging logic> on indexed columns or only keys, you have to choose appropriate slicer accordingly (RangeSlicesQuery, IndexedSlicesQuery, MultigetSliceQuery). See the hectors examples https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example